# During installing package in RStudio, error occured

Tags: r, rstudio

After

```
install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github("DataComputing/DataComputing")
```

First, it gave the error message

```
'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Error: Command failed (1)
```

So, I uninstalled and reinstalled in C: (rather than C:programfiles), and tried again, and now new error message

```
Downloading GitHub repo DataComputing/DataComputing@master
from URL https://api.github.com/repos/DataComputing/DataComputing/zipball/master
Installing DataComputing
"C:/R-32~1.3/bin/i386/R" --no-site-file --no-environ --no-save --no-restore CMD INSTALL  \ 
C:/Users/lunar0412/AppData/Local/Temp/Rtmp8GOyFS/devtools2f0c1ba705f/DataComputing-
DataComputing-847764c" --library="C:/R-3.2.3/library" --install-tests 

* installing *source* package 'DataComputing' ...
** R
Error in parse(outFile) : 
invalid multibyte character in parser at line 36
ERROR: unable to collate and parse R files for package 'DataComputing'
* removing 'C:/R-3.2.3/library/DataComputing'
Error: Command failed (1)
```

help me!! how to solve it??

Answer (score 0):

You can check changing the CRAN mirror when you are installing packages , some times back for me there was somewhat similar kind of problem , which was fixed by that.